# Suddenly I can't use the "Media" file uploader in Full HTML CKeditor edit screen but can do in Filtered HTML edit screen

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, media

I Use D7, CKeditor v 1.16.7 and Media v 1.5.7, all other modules are up2date and the site itself works fine.

I don't recall any special change at the site that would avoid this module of working, yet suddenly it's **upload button** was removed from CKeditor's Full HTML palette (img 1) while appearing fine in Filtered HTML palette.

Facts:

1. The CKeditor "Full HTML" profile's settings seems just fine (img 2).
2. Permissions are fine (I'm the Admin, img 3).
3. Rebuilding type information for media, didn't help.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is it showing any recent errors in the log related to either module?

Comment: Went to "Recent log messages" but couldn't find anything special there, at least not something relating to the phrase "Media".

Comment: It seems that the problem only occurs in "Full HTML" profile but not in "Filtered". I've corss-chekced the profiles' settings and couldn't find any differences... strange isn't it?..

Comment: it is - sorry, I don't have any suggestions for you... I was banking on an error

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the module?

Comment: yoursite.com/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full is not listed under available buttons?

Comment: not sure if media module has any check box in here, but might be worth checking admin/config/content/formats/full_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! For some reason (most probably a bug) the **Media module button** wasn't added automatically to the Full toolbar even after I check-marked "Plugin for inserting images from Drupal media module" in "Editor appearance" at the desired profile's settings page.

So, What I did was after I check-marked "Plugin for inserting images from Drupal media module" I just went on to add the button manually from "Available buttons" to "Current toolbar" (see img), saved, cleared cache, and Vwalla - it worked again!

[image]